# Save windows form fileds content into JSON file

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I have a windows form with some fields :

- Two **ListView** (`InputFields` and `OutputFields`)
- Three **TexBox** (`Title1`, `Title2` and `Title3`)
- Two **Buttons** (`Save To File` and `Read from File`)

#### My Problem :

When i click on the `Save To File` Button i want to save all the contents of the two `ListViews` and the three `TextBox` into a **JSON** file.

When i click on the `Read from File` i want to populate the `ListViews` and `TextBoxs` from **JSON** file.

**Knowing :**

I save the `Id` on the `Tag` of each item of `ListView`.

**Structure of my JSON File :**

```
{
    "title1": "example Title 1",
    "title2": "example Title 2",
    "title3": "example Title 3",

    "inputfields": {
        "item1": {
                    "name": "SGML",
                    "tag": "SGML"
                },
        "item2": {
                    "name": "SGML",
                    "tag": "SGML"
                },          
        ......

        "itemN": {
                    "name": "SGML",
                    "tag": "SGML"
                 }
           },

    "outputfields": {
        "item1": {
                    "name": "SGML",
                    "tag": "SGML"
                },
        "item2": {
                    "name": "SGML",
                    "tag": "SGML"
                },          
        ......

        "itemM": {
                    "name": "SGML",
                    "tag": "SGML"
                }
    }
}
```

Is there any function can do this work for me?

Thanks Stackoverflowers.

Comment: and where is your code? What did you do so far?

Comment: i dont do anything yet with the code, i just creat the form that's it, i am waiting to know if it's doable befor. The Json File is just there, to show the exemple how i want it to be.

Comment: See my answer Joe that is the best and cleanest way of doing this. You might need to tweak it a bit but it should give you the idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with a class that holds the data behind the scene and use a library like JSON.NET to serialize this class to Json and back...

[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

Answer (score 1):

ok that's very simple.

What you need to do is to first create an object called Filed which has Item objects in it. then Item object has two properties of tag and name. something like this. But note I haven't test the code,I just wrote it on notepad.but it should be something like this.

import this library : using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Then create this class:

```
    public class Field
{
    public Field(){}
    public Item item1{set; get;}
    public Item item2{set; get;}
    public Item item3{set; get;}

}
```

And another class called item

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item(){}
        public string name{set; get;}
        public string Tag{set; get;}

    }
```

then something like this :

```
List<Field> Items = new List<Field>{
                   new Field{item1 = new Item{name:title1.Text, Tag.Text}, item2 = new Item{name:title1.Text, Tag.Text}, item3 = new Item{name:title1.Text, Tag.Text}},
                   new Field{item2 = new Item{name:title1.Text, Tag.Text}, item2 = new Item{name:title1.Text, Tag.Text}, item3 = new Item{name:title1.Text, Tag.Text}},}
                   };


string jsonString = Items.ToJSON();
```

Answer (score 1):

It surely is possible. The easiest way is to define a class that corresponds to the JSON structure, create an instance of it and populate it with the data from the fields, and then to serialize the object.

Analogically you can do the 'load from file' function. In that case you load the JSON, deserialize it into an object, and then populate the fields with the data from the object.

Considering the serialization / deserialization process itself you can find pretty good tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) or here.